Apply the Breusch-Pagan to uncover the source of variance in the data
For my research I am trying to uncover if the variance of my variable of interest is correlated with one of my independent variables. Let $ x $ be the independent variable of interest and $ m $ be the dependent variable. What I want to find out is that if the variance of $ m $ increases or decreases with $ x $
In addition to these two variables, my dataset contains other independent variables that I have to control due to possible confounding factors (for my example let call them $ z $ and $ y $)
To answer this question I am using the Breusch-Pagan, as indicated by some papers on my research field that tried to do the same thing. The paper I was looking at do not provide code, but only a short description of the process.
This is my current approach:
library(lmtest)
# Fit a linear regression
fit <- lm(df, "m  ~ x + z+ y")
#Apply bptest
test <- bptest(fit, varformula = "~ x") 

If the p.value of the test if less that my significant threshold, I say that the variability of $ m $ is dependent on $ x $
I am however, unsure this is the correct approach. As I understand, the Breusch-Pagan method test for heteroscedasticity by fiting an auxiliary regression on the square of residuals of the original regression, and then test for associations between the residuals and the independent variables.
As such, I am unsure if I should also use $ x $ my variable of interest when fitting the original regression, or If I should omit it and just use it in the bptest function

Have you tried visualizing the source of non-constant variance? For example, with residuals vs one of the predictors, or a scale-location plot?

@Frans Rodenburg
I did not yet. I simplified the question, but in reality I have to fit many datasets (~850 000). The expectation is that only some of them will have non-constant variance depending on the variable of interest. What you are suggesting is more a downstream analysis

Then why not opt for a model where the variance is allowed to vary? Or compute heteroscedasticity-robust standard errors? For any level of $\alpha$, you are going to incorrectly conclude non-constant variance for $850,000 \cdot \alpha$ analyses.

Because my objective is not to build a robust model, but to understand the variation of $ m $ increases or decreases in function of $ x $. Also,  I was expecting more than $ 850,00 $ $alpha$ significant results

Okay, thanks for clarifying, I recommend adding this to the question. As for an answer, I don't have something comprehensive, other than that different heteroscedasticity tests have different sensitivities. Depending on what kind of variance increase along $x$ you expect or find more interesting, it might be easier to choose an approach. Finally, model that allow the variance to depend on $x$ (like robust regression) can actually be used to quantify the extent of increasing variance with $x$.

Hi: I don't think the breusch pagan test is the way to go because, as you said, it's original intent is not what you're trying to do. Can't you just take the variances as the dependent variable and the other variable as the dependent variable and then run an OLS and look at the coefficient of the variances  variable and its significance ? Obviously, you're leaving variables out ( which could bias the results ) but it's a first step.
